# Showing items as images in a WPF ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, image

So I have binded a `List` to a `ListView` where the `List` has items of type `Album`, where it has lots of properties including `.Cover`, which I is an image on disk. Well since I don't know what type of image is needed and how they have to be loaded (I only know using Image types for Winforms), I don't know the type yet.

Can someone show or post me a quick sample where it shows this sort of items being shown as images of a certain fixed size using their `.Cover` property?

In essence this would show:

1. What type `.Cover` should be
2. How to open images from disk for WPF (assuming it's different than Winforms image loading)
3. How to show them on a ListView as images of a **certain fixed size**, scaling the images if necessary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. ImageSource
2. ImageSource myImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"file://C:... something.jpg"));
3. Specify a data template for the items in the ListView's ItemTemplate property:

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Image Width="10" Height="10" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Cover}"/>
           <Label Content="{Binding Title}" />
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>

   <Grid x:Name="grid">
       <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}" />
   </Grid>
   ```

Comment: Note that the image can also be sourced from a resource, it doesn't have to come directly from disk. (The resource can be part of the current executing assembly, or it can be in a separate referenced assembly). It can even be a URL to a web address.

Comment: Thanks slugster how do you do that?

Answer (score 2):

In xaml you'd define a `DataTemplate` in your Listview's `ItemTemplate` that uses an `Image`, binding it's `Source` property to a path on your file sysem.

In other words, `Cover` can be of type string, a file path. If you want to scale, a pretty simple way is a `ViewBox`, which scales all it contains. However, Image itself probably has options to do scaling.

Comment: Thanks, can you please show me code sample. I don't know ViewBox or the Image binding.