# WPF - bind images horizontally to ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570568/showing-items-as-images-in-a-wpf-listview) but following the answer there doesn't resolve this same issue. Images are still listed vertically. I am binding oData from NetFlix.

[image]

Following is the XAML :-

```
    <Window.Resources>
          <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageCell">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding BoxArt.MediumUrl}" Width="200" Height="200" Stretch="Fill" ToolTip="{Binding Synopsis}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

 <ListView Margin="21,40,26,9" Name="lvwTitles" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
 SelectionMode="Single" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageCell}">        
 </ListView>
```

Following is the code behind:-

```
List<Title> titles = serviceAccessor.GetAllTitlesByGenre(cmbGenre.SelectedValue.ToString());
lvwTitles.ItemsSource = titles;
```

Comment: Check this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041551/wpf-listview-with-horizontal-arrangement-of-items

Greetings

Comment: I have already seen that link and used WrapPanel and images still don't show horizontally and I believe Its certainly possible with stackpanel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the stackpanel in the wrong place.  The stackpanel in the datatemplate just creates a stackpanel containing one single image, for each item in the listview.  Try setting the itemspanel.. something like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
...
</ListView>
```