# Image Upload and Image Slider

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

- In my C# WPF windows Application I want to create a control similar to File-Upload in web applications ... of course there won't be server in windows application to save uploaded images
- I used Text Box and 2 buttons (Browse) and (Upload):

  - I want when I press (Browse) button ...open file dialogue to search for my images in my computer
  - when I choose image ... its path appear in text box
  - when I press (Upload) button ..image is saved in my database and shown in an Images slider
- also I ask about how to make that Image slider
- if I have 3 upload controls in the same window but every one is related to certain content .. and all images uploaded by 3 upload controls are shown in image slider .. can I Link each image with its own content when I try to preview a summary for my work??
- Note: I looked for many questions here related to what I want .. but there is no clear answer with correct code ..so I wish you can help me ..thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you need an Horizontal ListView that is bounded to list of objects, when the object contains path to image, and summary.

you can get direction from here:

[wpf-bind-images-horizontally-to-listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457872/wpf-bind-images-horizontally-to-listview)

Whenever you click the upload button all you have to do is just to add a new object with the selected path to the bounded list.

about the two arrow buttons - you have to see how to change the listview horizontal scrollbar control template.

[Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF)

Comment: what about the most important part ... making upload control?? don't u have idea about to make it and link it with what u explained?? thank you