# Image not appearing in listview - just showing the text "system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage"

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview

I am having problems with a listview in WPF C#. I have a class called FaultRecords which contains an integer field, a bitmap image and a string. When I run the code the integer and string appear fine but the image does not. In the column where the image is supposed to be I just get the path to the type instead - "system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage". Its driving me crazy.....

Here's my code

```
public void RecordNewFault()
{
    FaultRecords myRecord = new FaultRecords(FaultIndex, PublicVars.SrcBmp, "Hi There!");
    lstvFaults.Items.Add(myRecord);

}

public class FaultRecords
{
    private int _faultNumber;
    public int FaultNumber
    {
        get { return _faultNumber; }
        set { _faultNumber = value; }
    }


    public BitmapImage _faultImage;
    public BitmapImage FaultImage
    {
        get { return _faultImage; }
        set { _faultImage = value; }
    }


    private string _faultDescription;
    public string FaultDescription
    {
        get { return _faultDescription; }
        set { _faultDescription = value; }
    }


    public FaultRecords(int faultNumber, BitmapImage faultImage, string faultDescription) 
    {
        FaultDescription = faultDescription;
        FaultNumber = faultNumber;
        FaultImage = faultImage;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <ListView Height="412" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="312,49,0,0"         Name="lstvFaults" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="636" ItemsSource="{Binding}"    FontSize="12"> 
                              <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FaultNumber}"
                                Header="Fault No." Width="50"/>
                            <GridViewColumn 
                               DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FaultImage}"
                                Header="Photo" Width="150"/>
                        <GridViewColumn 
                               DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FaultDescription}"
                            Header="Fault Description" Width="300"/>
                    </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
```

If I just write the Bitmap to the listview on it's own (and remove the XAML bindings) -   `lstvFaults.Items.Add(PublicVars.SrcBmp);` it works fine.

Comment: You have to override the ListView ItemTemplate with a custom template that binds your image to an Image object.

Comment: @Blam I thought I had got it working but I alas have not. I am now using a class to bind to my listview, this works fine. However it does not show the image in the listview it displays the type instead.

Comment: I am talking about your other questions.

Answer (score 1):

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570568/showing-items-as-images-in-a-wpf-listview?rq=1).

You need to tell the ListView to render the content not as Text (hence it is showing you the Type), but as an Image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a DataTemplate. See a simplified example [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/gridviewcolumn-displaymemberbinding-vs-celltemplate/).
Also you will need an ImageSource and not a BitmapImage! Sorry :(

Comment: Thanks noorbakhsh - I had actually figured this out myself and was coming here to close the question :-), as soon as I changed to ImageSource it worked.